# Ограничение стандартных библиотек через Python venv

Tags: python, virtualenv

Работаю с проектом, главная суть которого является исполнением клиентского кода.
`Цель` - пытаюсь ограничить пользовательский код в использовании библиотек, в частности и стандартных, таких как *urllib*, *os*, *sys*

`Проблема` - все попытки ограничения стандартных библиотек приводят ни к чему.

Были два стула:

- запуск скрипта путём аргументов `python -I -S script.py`
- работа с `pyenv`. Во втором случае все кажется более гуманным в случае отключения импорта `site-packages`, но со стандартными библиотеками так не работает.

Есть ли решение? 

**Ещё раз**: мне нужно отключить подгрузку библиотек, таких как *urllib*, *os*, *sys*, *threading* и т.д.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь оградить себя от потенциальных угроз безопасности этим?

Comment: @nomnoms12 да, именно так!

Comment: @nomnoms12 я просто банально не хочу работать с правами директории, выполнять код от пользователя без прав, работать с правилами входящего и исходящего трафика, если всё же есть способ решение в самом ЯП

Comment: @nomnoms12 всё дело в том, что пользователю не нужны будут эти библиотеки, поскольку кодом он будет решать поставленную перед ним задачу (турнир по информатике, вот как здорово!), но предостеречься всегда нужно.

Comment: Простое удаление стандартных библиотек не отгородит Вас от угроз безопасности, а лишь нарушит работу ЯП. Для Вашего случая есть готовые решения, например, можно исполнять код в контейнере `Docker`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 хорошо, учту.